# Memcached high insert/update cause the deadlocks

Tags: php, memcached

I am recording unique page views using memcached and storing them in db at 15 mins interval. Whenever number of users grow memcached gives me following error:

```
Memcache::get(): Server localhost (tcp 10106) failed with: Failed reading line from stream (0)
```

I am using following code for insert/update page views in memcached

```
if($memcached->is_valid_cache("visiors")) {
    $log_views = $memcached->get_cache("visiors");
    if(!is_array($log_views)) $log_views = array();
}
else {
    $log_views = array();
}
$log_views[] = array($page_id, $time, $other_Stuff);
$memcached->set_cache("visiors", $log_views, $cache_expire_time);
```

Following code retrieves the array from memcached, updates the X number of page views in db and sets the remaining page views in memcached

```
if($memcached->is_valid_cache("visiors")) {
   $log_views = $memcached->get_cache("visiors");
   if(is_array($log_views) && count($log_views) > 0) {
        $logs = array_slice($log_views, 0, $insert_limit);        
        $insert_array = array();
        foreach($logs as $log) {
            $insert_array[] = '('. $log[0]. ',' . $log[1] . ', NOW())';
        }
        $insert_sql = implode(',',$insert_array);
        if(mysql_query('INSERT SQL CODE')) {
            $memcached->set_cache("visiors", array_slice($log_views, $insert_limit), $cache_expire_time); //store new values
        }
    }
 }
```

The insert/update cause thread locking because I can see lots of script in waiting for their turn. I think I am losing page views during the update process. Any suggestions how to avoid memcached reading errors and make this code perfect?

Comment: Memcached is locking. That's a feature of it. Switch to a properly configured MySQL backend, it can be much faster with congruent access and handles locking better.

Comment: Mysql does not work well with high inserts thats reason I added memcached layer.

Comment: I beg to differ. But anyway, if memcached loocks you up with high inserts (now), you need to switch again to something else that does not. As said, can be done with MySQL, but naturally you're not bound to MySQL.

Comment: How do you propose MySQL solution? Just simple INSERT statements? The avg insert rate is 500-600 per sec.

Comment: 500-600 is by no stretch of the imagination "high."  I can sustain 400,000/s (just under 100,000 times your rate) indefinitely on my laptop with the latest release, and there's new optimizations going in real soon now to get you closer to 800,000/s - 900,000/s on this same hardware.  Your usage might be suboptimal, but it's not the rates.

Comment: @Dustin Is it batch insert or one insert at a time? Do you run select during insert? Sometimes insert locked up during select queries.

Comment: It simply doesn't matter.  memcached doesn't have a "batch" insert.  It doesn't know whether you're talking to a database between sets.  It just takes tiny discrete operations and applies them.  memcached has no problem processing 1,000x more data than you're throwing at it.  That's not where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into a connection limit within memcached, your firewall, network, etc. We have a simple walk through on the most common scenarios: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Timeouts

There's no internal locking that would cause sets or gets to block for any amount of time.